# Return dynamic field with Linq query and EntityFrameworkCore 2.2

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following POCOs;

```
public class Trader : AuditableEntity
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Telephone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address : AuditableEntity
{
    public Trader Trader { get; set; }
    /* reduce for brevity*/

    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    public IPoint Location { get; set; }
}
```

The current need is to be able to pull back a `List<Trader>` from a search using the `NetTopologySuite` based on a passed in Lat, Long and Distance. This is currently by our service as follows;

```
var currentLocation = new Point((double)customerLongitude, (double)customerLatitude) { SRID = 4326 };

var traders = context.Where<Trader>(x => x.Addresses.Any(y => y.Location.IsWithinDistance(currentLocation, distanceFromCustomer)));
```

Prior to migrating over to `EntityFrameworkCore` 2.2 a stored procedure would be used. In the stored procedure I could dynamically return the distance that the trader lat long was from the passed in lat long as well as the return data;

```
Distance = (@GEO1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(Latitude,0.000000),ISNULL(Longitude,0.000000), 4326)))
```

Is it possible for me to use linq to dynamically geolocate and select the distance in the same way the stored proc would and add it to the return efficiently?